# How to migrate from DB2 or Oracle to TiDB?

Tags: oracle, db2, distributed-database, tidb

I want to try TiDB and I am working on data migration. Is there any way of migrating data from DB2 or Oracle to TiDB?

Answer (score 1):

If using OGG to sync data to TiDB, you should `set global tidb_constraint_check_in_place = 1` to disable the lazy-constraint-check in TiDB.

Answer (score 0):

To migrate all the data or migrate incrementally from DB2 or Oracle to TiDB, you can use one of the following solutions:

- Use the official migration tool of Oracle, such as OGG, Gateway, CDC (Change Data Capture).
- Develop a program for importing and exporting data.
- Export Spool as text file, and import data using Load infile.
- Use a third-party data migration tool.

Currently, it is recommended to use OGG.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL Developer will capture and convert your LUW DB2 database and create it in an existing Oracle Database as new schema(s). It will move the data for you too.

Here's where you can go to learn [more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/index-084442.html)